# How to update pandas DataFrame.drop() for Future Warning - all arguments of DataFrame.drop except for the argument 'labels' will be keyword-only

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The following code:

```
df = df.drop('market', 1)
```

generates the warning:

> FutureWarning: In a future version of pandas all arguments of DataFrame.drop except for the argument 'labels' will be keyword-only

`market` is the column we want to drop, and we pass the `1` as a second parameter for axis (0 for index, 1 for columns, so we pass 1).

How can we change this line of code now so that it is not a problem in the future version of pandas / to resolve the warning message now?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

From the documentation, [`pandas.DataFrame.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) has the following parameters:

Parameters

> - **labels**: single label or list-like Index or column labels to drop.
> - **axis**: {0 or ‘index’, 1 or ‘columns’}, default 0 Whether to drop labels from the index (0 or ‘index’) or columns (1 or ‘columns’).
> - **index**: single label or list-like Alternative to specifying axis (labels, axis=0 is equivalent to index=labels).
> - **columns**: single label or list-like Alternative to specifying axis (labels, axis=1 is equivalent to columns=labels).
> - **level**: int or level name, optional For MultiIndex, level from which the labels will be removed.
> - **inplace**: bool, default False If False, return a copy. Otherwise, do operation inplace and return None.
> - **errors**: {‘ignore’, ‘raise’}, default ‘raise’ If ‘ignore’, suppress error and only existing labels are dropped.

Moving forward, only `labels` (the first parameter) can be positional.

---

So, for this example, the `drop` code should be as follows:

```
df = df.drop('market', axis=1)
```

or (more legibly) with `columns`:

```
df = df.drop(columns='market')
```

Answer (score 17):

The reason for this warning is so that probably in future versions pandas will change the `*args` to `**kwargs`.

So that means specifying `axis` would be required, so try:

```
df.drop('market', axis=1)
```

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/args_and_kwargs.html#usage-of-kwargs):

> **kwargs allows you to pass keyworded variable length of arguments to a function. You should use **kwargs if you want to handle named arguments in a function.

Also recently with the new versions (as of 0.21.0), you could just specify `columns` or `index` like this:

```
df.drop(columns='market')
```

See more [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.21.0.html#method-drop-now-also-accepts-index-columns-keywords).